# Looking for a simple Java API for creating graphs (edges + nodes)

Tags: java, api, graph-theory

I'm trying to find a simple Java API for creating graph relationships. It should have some functionality like `addEdge()`, `addNode()`, `isConnected(node1, node2)`, `findPaths(node1, node2)`, etc.  I need no UI, just logic.

I found a bunch of academic projects, but none seems to be "*The Definitive Graph API*".

Does anyone know about such an API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org) sounds like what you're after.

> JGraphT is a free Java graph library that provides mathematical graph-theory objects and algorithms. JGraphT supports various types of graphs.

Their API can create graphs from various input and also supports creating graphs using `addVertex`, `addEdge`. They support finding shortest paths using various well know algorithms such as Bellman-Ford and Dijkstra They also have a complete [javadoc available online](http://www.jgrapht.org/javadoc/).

Comment: how can one create minimum spanning trees with JGraphT?

Comment: Note: JGraph which is a GUI can be used along with it.

Answer (score 3):

[JDLS](http://www.jdsl.org/) is a great library for Graphs and Datastructures in general. You could also use the [Grappa](http://www.research.att.com/~john/Grappa/) library. Its advantage is that it can use the [graphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) libraries for graph layouting.

Answer (score 2):

Definitly You should try the http://neo4j.org/
This is great Graph database written in Java but It can work as a embedded database to very small application too.

This database have everything You need even if you plan to store billions of nodes. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

a really decent one can be found here: http://javaddlib.sourceforge.net/jdd/

Answer (score 0):

*Jdigraph* is [yet another](http://java.net/projects/jdigraph) graph library.

Answer (score 0):

[JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) — the Java Universal Network/Graph Framework - is one of the fastest available (implementing the CERN math library COLT), especially if you want to do graph analysis, centrality measurements (betweennes, pagerank, etc.). Furthermore it allows for network visualization.