# List of Java APIs for graph/network data structures

Tags: java, collections, graph

What are some good Java APIs for working with graphs (edges/nodes) as data structures?

Please add references to similar SO questions in comments to this wiki.  Please edit the list in this wiki entry directly.  Please add summary description of your added projects as answers (one project per answer).

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745048/looking-for-a-simple-java-api-for-creating-graphs-edges-nodes

Answer (score 8):

I searched a lot for Java Graph Library in the web for my MS thesis.
I suggest you the following frameworks:

1. [GraphStream](http://graphstream-project.org): it has very simple API and it's plenty of algorithms. It offers many graph structures (directed, undirected, multigraph, ... ) and many visualisation tools.
2. [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net): this framework has been around for a while, so it has robust and well-tested features.
   Last release was in 2010, so the syntax is quite a bit old.

Both the frameworks have many algorithms and a visualisation tool.

If you are concerned about memory and performance, and you just need the graph data structure (no algorithms, no visualisation), I would suggest [AuroraGraphManager](https://github.com/besil/AuroraGraphManager), which is the graph data structure I implemented and part of my thesis. The frameworks I suggested above weren't good for me because I had to deal with quite big graphs (up to 300 million edges).

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/) - JGraphT is a free Java graph library that provides mathematical graph-theory objects and algorithms. JGraphT supports various types of graphs including:

- directed and undirected graphs.
- graphs with weighted / unweighted / labeled or any user-defined edges.
- various edge multiplicity options, including: simple-graphs, multigraphs, pseudographs.
- unmodifiable graphs - allow modules to provide "read-only" access to internal graphs.
- listenable graphs - allow external listeners to track modification events.
- subgraphs graphs that are auto-updating subgraph views on other graphs.
- all compositions of above graphs

(Requires Java 1.6)

Comment: JGraph appears to be for visualization.

Comment: I edited to remove JGraph as unsuitable and Jung as mentioned previously.  Now follows the one API per answer format...  Thanks to @Kaleb Brasee for original post.

Answer (score 4):

[JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) — the Java Universal Network/Graph Framework--is a software library that provides a common and extendible language for the modeling, analysis, and visualization of data that can be represented as a graph or network.

Answer (score 2):

[JDSL](http://www.cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/) - JDSL is the Data Structures Library in Java. It is a collection of Java interfaces and classes that implement fundamental data structures and algorithms, such as:

- sequences, trees, priority queues, search trees, hash tables
- sorting and searching algorithms
- graphs
- graph traversals, shortest path, minimum spanning tree

(JDSL does not appear to support generics)