# I get different behaviour in Java depending on HOW I initialize the data structures

Tags: java

I implemented an algorithm in Java. I coded two versions:

- one where I initialized the data structures in the constructor,
  and
- one where I parsed a textfile and initialized the data structure from the input

The strange thing is that I got different behaviour from the two versions, and can hardly understand how.

**Why do I get different behaviour?**

The algorithm is a first part of Depth-First Search. A set of nodes should be visited and printed **only once**. In my version where I read from a textfile, the first node is printed twice. The program uses recursion.

Here is the output, the code is below. The first four lines prints the data structures, then is each first-visit-of-a-node printed, and a counter. The counter should only go to 2 **not** 3.

*Output, when read from textfile:*

```
>java GraphStart ex1.txt
Node 1
Node 2
Edge: Node 1 -- Node 2
Edge: Node 2 -- Node 1

Start on Node 1
Node 1 Counter: 1
Node 2 Counter: 2
Node 1 Counter: 3
```

*Output, when initialized in constructor:*

```
Node 1
Node 2
Edge: Node 1 -- Node 2
Edge: Node 2 -- Node 1

Start on Node 1
Node 1 Counter: 1
Node 2 Counter: 2
```

*Depth-First Search - initialized in contructor:*

```
public class DepthFirstSearch {
    private final static LinkedList<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
    private static LinkedList[] edges = new LinkedList[0];

    public DepthFirstSearch() {

        Node node1 = new Node(1);
        Node node2 = new Node(2);

        nodes.add(node1);
        nodes.add(node2);

        edges = Arrays.copyOf(edges, 1);
        edges[0] = new LinkedList<Edge>();
        edges[0].add(new Edge(node1, node2));

        edges = Arrays.copyOf(edges, 2);
        edges[1] = new LinkedList<Edge>();
        edges[1].add(new Edge(node2, node1));

        DFS.startDFS(nodes, edges);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DepthFirstSearch();
    }
}
```

*Depth-First Search - initialized from textfile:*

```
public class GraphStart {
    private final static LinkedList<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<Node>();
    private static LinkedList[] edges = new LinkedList[0];

    public GraphStart(String fileName) {
        scanFile(fileName);

        DFS.startDFS(nodes, edges);
    }

    // Parse a textfile with even number of integers
    // Add the nodes and edges to the datastructures
    private static void scanFile(String filename) {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filename));

            while(sc.hasNextInt()){
                Node startNode = new Node(sc.nextInt());
                if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    Node endNode = new Node(sc.nextInt());

                    if(!nodes.contains(startNode)){
                        nodes.add(startNode);
                        //EDIT
                        System.out.println("Added " + startNode);

                        // Grow the Edge-array and initialize the content
                        if(edges.length < startNode.getNr())
                            edges = Arrays.copyOf(edges, startNode.getNr());

                        edges[startNode.getNr()-1] = new LinkedList<Edge>();
                    }

                    if(!nodes.contains(endNode)){
                        nodes.add(endNode);
                        //EDIT
                        System.out.println("Added " + endNode);

                        // Grow the Edge-array and initialize the content
                        if(edges.length < endNode.getNr())
                            edges = Arrays.copyOf(edges, endNode.getNr());

                        edges[endNode.getNr()-1] = new LinkedList<Edge>();
                    }

                    // Add the Edge
                    edges[startNode.getNr()-1].add(new Edge(startNode, endNode));
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Can not find the file:" + filename);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length==1) {
            new GraphStart(args[0]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong argument. <filename>");
        } 
    }
}
```

*Textfile for input:*

```
1 2
2 1
```

It represents the Edge from Node 1 to Node 2, and the Edge from Node 2 to Node 1.

The algorithm is implemented in a static file, used by both versions.
*DFS - the algorithm:*

```
public class DFS {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private static LinkedList<Node> nodes;
    private static LinkedList[] edges;

    public static void startDFS(LinkedList<Node> ns, LinkedList[] es) {
        nodes = ns;
        edges = es;

        /* Print the data structures */ 
        printList(nodes);
        printEdges(edges);

        for(Node n : nodes) {
            if(!n.isVisited()) {
                System.out.println("\nStart on "+n);
                dfs(n);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void dfs(Node n) {
    counter++;
    n.visit();
    System.out.println(n + " Counter: "  + counter);
    for(Object o : edges[n.getNr()-1]) {
        if(!((Edge)o).getEnd().isVisited()) {
            dfs(((Edge)o).getEnd());
        }
    }

    private static void printList(LinkedList<?> list) {
        for(Object obj : list)
            System.out.println(obj);
    }

    private static void printEdges(LinkedList[] edges) {
        for(LinkedList list : edges) {
            System.out.print("Edge: ");
            for(Object o : list) {
                System.out.print(o);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Added code listings of Node and Edge.

*Node:*

```
public class Node {
    private final int nr;
    private boolean visited = false;

    public Node(int nr) {
        this.nr = nr;
    }

    public int getNr()          { return nr; }
    public boolean isVisited()  { return visited; }
    public void visit()         { visited = true; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof Node)
            return ((Node)obj).getNr() == nr;
        else
            return false;
        }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node " + nr;
    }
}
```

*Edge:*

```
public class Edge {
    private final Node startNode;
    private final Node endNode;

    public Edge(Node start, Node end) {
        this.startNode = start;
        this.endNode = end;
    }

    public Node getStart()      { return startNode; }
    public Node getEnd()        { return endNode; }

    public String toString() {
        return startNode + " " + 
            "--" + " " +
            endNode;
    }
}
```

Sorry for the very long code listings. I tried to isolate my problem and also show a runnable program.

Comment: You have syntax errors. Like no close brace on the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have corrected the close brace on the constructor now. It's hard to write long code listings here, my mistake.

Comment: You might consider using exisiting APIs for building and iterating graph structures (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152143/list-of-java-apis-for-graph-network-data-structures)

Comment: That's true harshware! I will change my implementation. But the question is WHY i get different behaviour. I'll try to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: The different behavior is because in one case you have two nodes instances and in another case you have three.  Figuring out the detailed reasons why is trickier but I've made a stab below.

Comment: You are rigt, see my comment on your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the code for Node, my guess is that it isn't implementing hashCode() and equals() or that these aren't implemented correctly.

So for example:

```
if(!nodes.contains(startNode)){
    nodes.add(startNode);
```

Will be doing the containment check with reference equality (==) instead of anything logical.  So the fact that you've create three different node instances will not resolve even though two are "the same".

...and that's why the static method version works because you only have two node instances.

Edit: the above was a good guess but reading deeper into the code I think it has to do with the fact that visit state is kept right on the nodes instead of in a separate visited collection.  You have three node instances in your graph even if only two are in the nodes list.  One of the edges is pointing to the third node instance (the other one with a '1')... since the visited() method was never called on that one (because it was called on the first '1' instance) then isVisited() will likely return false (can't say for sure because I don't know your Node implementation).

Comment: Pretty sure it's my second guess.  The last edge points to a different Node(1) instance with its own visited state.  Usually less than ideal to keep visited state right on the node when the depth first traverser can keep that in a hashset.

Comment: ...otherwise, your loader needs to resolve all .equals() instances to one common instance for each logical set.  And the other side-effect of keeping visited state right on the nodes is that you could never do two traversals at the same time.  Not even sort of.

Comment: You are right! It's no problem with .equals(), but I implemend Edge in a very wrong way. Because I store the Nodes in the Edge, so even if the Nodes have the same value, different instances are saved in Edge. Thank's a lot, it was a tricky one, at least for me.

Comment: If I were taking over this code, I'd fix the hashCode() in Node and base the graph off of a Map<Node,List<Edge>>.  For the DFS traversal, I'd have a visited HashSet<Node> and just check if( add(node) ) to see if the node had been visited or not (add returns true when node hasn't been visited).  Glad you got your solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

You did not show the implementation for `Node`, but I would guess that you did not override `equals()` for it. This will lead `nodes.contains(node)` to return false and more nodes to be added to the collection than wanted. (The file reading loop creates a fresh start- and endNode everytime through the loop.)

Your constuctor version simply uses 2 unique nodes, which gives the different result.

Implementing `Node.equals()` will probably solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I added the code listing for Node and Edge now. I have implemented equals, but I must check again that it is correct. Anyway, I have the print out of the data structures in the output. If I have two nodes of the same, I should see it there.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scanFile()` method creates three nodes - two containing the integer `1`, and one containing the integer `2`.

Comment: No, I check if nodes contains the node before adding. Check my output-listing, where the two first lines list all nodes in the data structure.

Comment: Yes, you are right! The problem is that I store a reference to wrong instance of the nodes in Edge. Thanks a lot! 1up for your answer!