# Java Graph and Graph Search APIs

Tags: java, collections, graph

I'm in a position where I need to model a set of JavaBeans in a graph structure, where each bean is a node/vertex on the graph, and they are "connected"/related to one another via and edge.

So, just like one would use a `List<?>` or `ArrayList<?>` to represent a sequence of items, I need a (preferably generic) API for representing nodes in a graph. This API needs to allow me to build the graph, add/remove nodes from the graph however I like, etc.

Also, I need to be able to search the entire graph by passing it an arbitrary data value, and it will return the node/vertex that contains that data.

The only thing I can find is the built-in Java `TreeSet`, but I don't need a directed tree that flows from a single root node.  I need a true (in the mathematical sense) graph API.

Does such a solution exist out there or am I stuck writing my own from scratch (uggghhh). Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's not really a great deal to it.  `class Node { private List<Node> neighbours; }`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of Java APIs for graph/network data structures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152143/list-of-java-apis-for-graph-network-data-structures)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it well you need a representation of a "Node" object that:

1) Allows you to store values, so you can later search for the right node

2) Use a predefined data structure to to hold the graph's info.

3) Allow to be used by search algorithms.

There is a trivial solution that accomplishes all three demands:

```
public class Node {

    // Add as many fields as you need to contain the node info
    private String mName;
    private int mArbitraryValue;

    // Store the adjacent nodes in a list
    private List<Node> mAdjacencyList;

    //Define your constructors
    public Node(String name, int arbitraryValue, List<Node> adjacencyList) {
        mName = name;
        mArbitraryValue = arbitraryValue;
        mAdjacencyList = adjacencyList;
    }

    /* Add your methods here depending on the functionality that
       you want to implement
    */

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public int getArbitraryValue() {
        return mArbitraryValue;
    }

    public List<Node> getNeighbors() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(mAdjacencyList);
    }

    // Add setters if you want these values to be able to change

    public boolean addNeighbor(Node n) {
        return !mAdjacencyList.contains((Node) n) && mAdjacencyList.add(n);
    }

    public boolean removeNeighbor(Node n) {
        return mAdjacencyList.remove((Node) n);
    }
}
```

I don't recommend that you implement the adjacency list using a HashMap if your objects can be changed, because it can cause the set to break (ie calls to contains() can return false even if the object is present).

Now, your search algorithms can access the node's member variables to check if they are done.