# Two-dimensional List in Java

Tags: java, list

Is there a way to handle Lists in Java as twodimensional?

The situation:
I have a graph with nodes, edges and weight per edge. Now I need a data structure to store for each node:
a) its neighbours
b) the edge's weight for each neigbour

First I thought of creating a new class "node" with an identifyer and something like a two-dimensional array to store neighbour-identifyers and edge-weights. But the number of neighbours for each node is not given and may increase dynamically during runtime. Therefore I think two-dimensional arrays are not the way to go here.

I thought it would be possible to have in the class "node" a list like:

```
List<node> neighbours = new ArrayList<node>();
```

But obviously this only handles the neighbour nodes - not the weights of their edges.

Does anybody have a hint how to construct such a "graph" where for every node the neighbour's identifyers and the corresponding edge weight are stored?

Thank you for reading :-)

Comment: A 2 dimensional array would do, but if implementing it 2D array way is not necessary and you are flexible. May I suggest use of MAPS in java ? 

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745048/looking-for-a-simple-java-api-for-creating-graphs-edges-nodes

Comment: [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/) is awesome and a great alternative to Java's maps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most straight-forward is to use `HashMap`:

```
    class Edge {
// represents edge with destination node and it's weight
        private final Node node;
        private final int weight;

        Edge(Node node, int weight) {
            this.node = node;
            this.weight = weight;
        }

    }

// represents map which holds all outgoing edges keyed by source nodes.
    Map<Node, Set<Edges>> edgesByOutgoingNodes = new HashMap<Node, Set<Edges>>();
```

Comment: @coroner HashMap is the way to go.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
List<Connection> connections = new ArrayList<Connection>();
```

Where 'Connection' is defined as:

```
Class Connection {
    private int weight;
    private Node node;

    .... add getters/setters here ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Table](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) interface in Guava might be of some use. Ive never used it but Ive heard it's good. This [create](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html#create%28int,%20int%29) method may be of some use