# How to sort a multimap by complex key?

Tags: java, sorting, guava

Let's assume that we have a multimap

```
Multimap<List<Integer>, String> map = HashMultimap.create();

map.put(asList(1), "a");
map.put(asList(1), "b");
map.put(asList(1), "c");
map.put(asList(2), "d");
map.put(asList(3), "e");
map.put(asList(3), "f");
map.put(asList(1), "g");
map.put(asList(1), "h");
map.put(asList(1), "i");
map.put(asList(1), "j");
map.put(asList(1), "k");
map.put(asList(1, 2), "l");
map.put(asList(1, 2), "m");
map.put(asList(1, 2), "n");
map.put(asList(1, 2), "o");
map.put(asList(3), "p");
map.put(asList(3), "q");
map.put(asList(3), "r");
map.put(asList(7,3), "s");
map.put(asList(7), "t");
```

The key of map represents a connection id. `1` connected to `2` and `3` connected to `7`. I want to get all symbols filtered by connection id

```
1&2 : a,b,c,d,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o
7&3 : e,f,p,q,r,s,t
```

How can I do that via Guava?

Comment: Why the key is a list? It would be much easier if the key would be an Integer.

Comment: @carbolymer some of the keys contain multiple ints

Comment: Right, but, you're writing that the key represents a connection, so It would be better if you would use pair here. Also, what is the meaning of the lists with the one element?

Comment: you should use some graph library to do this kind of stuff, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745048/looking-for-a-simple-java-api-for-creating-graphs-edges-nodes and https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/DirectedGraphDemo

Comment: @RC. Incoming [Guava 20 release will have graph library](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/package-summary.html) included.

Answer (score 1):

The key of your multimap actually does not represent a connection id but a list of connection ids.

What you have:

```
{[1]=[a, b, c, g, h, i, j, k], [2]=[d], [3]=[p, q, r, e, f], [1, 2]=[l, m, n, o], [7]=[t], [7, 3]=[s]}
```

What I think you need:

```
{1=[a, b, c, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o], 2=[d, l, m, n, o], 3=[e, f, p, q, r, s], 7=[s, t]}
```

I recommend simply using `Multimap<Integer, String>` instead of `Multimap<List<Integer>, String>`:

```
Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multimap.put(1, "a");
multimap.put(1, "b");
multimap.put(1, "c");
multimap.put(2, "d");
multimap.put(3, "e");
multimap.put(3, "f");
multimap.put(1, "g");
multimap.put(1, "h");
multimap.put(1, "i");
multimap.put(1, "j");
multimap.put(1, "k");
multimap.put(1, "l");
multimap.put(1, "m");
multimap.put(1, "n");
multimap.put(1, "o");
multimap.put(2, "l");
multimap.put(2, "m");
multimap.put(2, "n");
multimap.put(2, "o");
multimap.put(3, "p");
multimap.put(3, "q");
multimap.put(3, "r");
multimap.put(7, "s");
multimap.put(3, "s");
multimap.put(7, "t");
System.out.println("1 & 2 : " + ImmutableSet.copyOf(Multimaps.filterKeys(multimap, i ->
        i == 1 || i == 2).values()));
System.out.println("7 & 3 : " + ImmutableSet.copyOf(Multimaps.filterKeys(multimap, i ->
        i == 7 || i == 3).values()));
```

Example Output:

```
1 & 2 : [a, b, c, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, d]
7 & 3 : [e, f, p, q, r, s, t]
```

Comment: But I need to keep connections between numbers. `1 -> 2`, `3 -> 7`, etc

Comment: Isn't that a [separate concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) though? The numbers can be associated with strings and the numbers can be associated with one another, right? We can keep track of each type of association in different data structures. e.g. A `Multimap<Integer, String>` can be used to track the first type while a `BiMap<Integer, Integer>` or a `Graph<Integer>` could be used to track the latter type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams for this if you have Java 8 or newer.

```
List<String> ones = map.entries().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains(1))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This example will produce a list with all the values that have `1` in their key but it can easily be modified to do ones with `1` or `2`, `1` and `2`, or anything else you want. Here's one that will do `1` or `2`:

```
List<String> onesAndTwos = map.entries().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains(1) || entry.getKey().contains(2))
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Does map have a `stream` method?

Comment: @Finkelson No, but its `entrySet()` does - see the first code line. But this doesn't matter as it all it's just a fancy Java 8 way of looping through all the entries, i.e., something rather inefficient.